# Сделать INSERT и получить значение уникального _id

Tags: php, mongodb

Привет. У меня есть json-массив, который я с клиента отправляю к PHP при помощи AJAX-запроса. Хочу положить этот массив в базу данных, но при этом сделать это так, чтобы он был доступен по уникальному `_id`:

```
function rememberSearch($data) {
    $mongo = new MongoClient();
    $db = $mongo->flaut;
    $collection = $db->searches;
    $array = json_decode($data, true);
    $collection->insert($array);
}
```

Хочу сделать так, чтобы эта функция возвращала значение `_id` записи, которую я сделал.

**@Mike** возвращается пустая строка:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['data']) && !empty($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    //создание соединения
    $mongo = new MongoClient();
    //выбор базы
    $db = $mongo->flaut;
    //выбор коллекции
    $collection = $db->searches;
    //декодирование массива
    $content = json_decode($data, true);
    //вставка в баху
    $collection->insert($content);
    //возвращение id
    echo $content['_id'];
}
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525556/mongodb-php-get-id-of-new-document

Comment: @Mike обновил вопрос.

Comment: Но вы почему то данные помещаете в переменную `$content`, а в БД вставляете переменную `$array`, которую до этого даже не объявляете. Пользуйтесь все таки одной и той же переменной ...

Comment: @Mike всё равно пустая строка.

Comment: @Mike обновил..

Comment: @Mike очевидно, что у меня неверно подключена сама mongodb. Я сделал `apt-get install mongodb-org -y` и сделал 'extension=mongodb.so' в php.ini. Возможно, я что-то пропустил?

Comment: а второй ответ из той ссылки пробовали ? там где явно получаем id перед вставкой. А если бы что то было не так подключено, очевидно были бы ошибки выполнения (на которые наверное надо проверять и сообщать о них)

Comment: @Mike попробовал, не сработало.

Comment: @Mike данные не вставляются в БД. Коллекция пуста.

Comment: @Mike так, у меня неправильно отправлялся AJAX-запрос. Теперь он отправляет данные к PHP, но теперь у меня ошибка ` Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found`